# POSTMAN - unable to fetch all the RESPONSE HEADERS including TOKEN

Tags: authentication, postman

I am trying to access the token from the Response Header of the POST request. However, when I POST the request in POSTMAN it doesn’t show all the Response headers which I see on the chrome dev tool.
The KEY in the response header I am after is :
location: https://app.rm.dev/auth/callback/?token=

Also, I can see when I POST the request I receive a GET request in the chain in the Console window [image attached]. I tried but was unable to get all the Response Headers, therefore is there a way I can copy the GET request Token value from the Console window shown in the Image?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, just needed to toggle off Auto redirect option in Postman Settings.